# How to make usernames display in rows and columns in a Table

Tags: php, html, mysql

I have this table im trying to display users, being 2 users per 2 columns, then list down. Here is what i have so far:

```
<?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from users WHERE adminlevel='5'");
        while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo
   " <table>
        <tr>
            <td width='85' align='left'><br><center>". $row['username'] . "</center>
            </td>
            <td align='right'><center></center>
            </td>
        </tr>
            <td width='85' align='left'><center></center>
            </td>
            <td align='right'><center></center>
            </td>

    </table>";


} ?>
```

This just displays the members as rows going down, and missing out the other column completely. I was hoping that it would display the username in each of the table fields. I also did try putting `". $row['username'] ."` in the other fields too, but that just duplicated it.

EDIT: 
So iv'e changed it to this, I can't see going down as I only have 2 members, Would this work:

```
         <?php $result = mysql_query("SELECT * from users WHERE adminlevel='5'"); ?>

         <table> 
            <tr>
             <?php while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) { echo
                "<td width='85' align='left'><font size='1px'><center>". $row['username'] . "</font></center></td>
                <td align='right'><center></center></td>"; 
              } ?>
             </tr>
        </table>
```

example:

[image]

Comment: You are using ancient HTML! Don't use `<center>`, `width='85'` or `align='left'`, use CSS!

Comment: You are making a `table` for every user.

Comment: You are building a new table for every username, build one table and only iterate through for the rows and columns.

Comment: I know, i was going to do this once I have done the $row correctly. then i was going to change it

Comment: What rows are you trying to get from the database?

Comment: at the moment, Just getting the usernames of who is admin. and they display correctly, just in the wrong form.

Comment: check my answer should do it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try something like this

```
        <table>
            <tr>
                <th>name</th>
                <th>name</th>
            </tr>
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT * from users WHERE adminlevel='5'");

$i = 0;
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result, MYSQL_ASSOC)) {
    if ($i == '0') echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>{$row['username']}</td>";
    if ($i == '1') echo "</tr>";  

    $i++;
    if($i =='2')$i='0';
}
?>
        </table>
```

Comment: @Joe Bills no problem dude.

Answer (score 0):

I think you're asking why the other fields in your "user" mysql table aren't showing up.

They aren't there because you only asked for the username:

```
$row['username']
```

If you have first/last name in your mysql table, you can retrieve it in the same way:

```
$row['firstname'] 
$row['lastname']
```

In your code you got the row as a key/value array like this:

```
$row = mysql_fetch_array($result)
```

The "key" is the name of the mysql column, like username, lastname, firstname. And the value is what is stored in the mysql table under that row/column, like joecool, smith, joe.

Comment: No, My users who are "admin" shows up correctly, Just they show going as a list, rather than going across.

Comment: Can you send add your output? That way we can see what is going on ;)

Comment: I'm reding the other comments and you said it's displaying in the wrong form... Can you send an example of the output you expect as well?

Comment: It is working, I just need some help on how to make it list 2 members accross then make it go down as a list.

Comment: Then make what go down as a list? More names? Or other fields?

Comment: iv'e added an image to the question

Comment: It looks like your new code will almost work, but if you want a new row, you'll need to add a <tr> before every odd (user1) and a </tr> after every even (user2)... Something like what @Jah posted ;)